# Did the Dursleys lock the door of Harry's cupboard at night?

Tags: harry-potter

In the beginning of the movie "Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone" there's a scene when Harry wakes up in his cupboard and Aunt Petunia opens like a bolt or something on the door.

So why did they lock him in? What if he needed to use the bathroom in the night or something?

Comment: I don't know why they locked Harry in, except maybe fear he'd try to escape.  By the first movie Harry was eleven, and it is quite possible that he didn't need to go to the bathroom in the night or that the Dursleys didn't care if he did.  People differ a lot in how often they have to go, and one person will differ in different ages of his life. Many people routinely sleep for eight hours straight without having to use the bathroom.  And I have often gone without using the bathroom for over eight hours when awake.

Comment: https://c1.staticflickr.com/8/7236/7012011167_72ce5dd3b8_b.jpg - I see at least two jars and a thermos that you could pee in.

Comment: They hardly cared about Harry's health and nourishment. So what makes you think they thought about his bathroom routine during the night.

Comment: Can't have that boy causing trouble on Dudley's birthday.

Comment: @Shreedhar They don’t care about *him*, but they’d care about their house not being peed in.

Comment: @Bellatrix well, you're right Bella. they were actually more worried about literally anything in the world except Harry :p

Comment: @Shreedhar Yes, and they liked to keep their house immaculately clean. I doubt they’d want Harry peeing on their floor or keeping a jar of it. We can’t have him soiling things. :P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## The Dursleys did lock the door sometimes, but not every night.

When Harry was being punished for letting the boa constrictor out at the zoo, he considered sneaking to the kitchen for some food, but knew he’d have to wait for the Dursleys to be asleep first. That would mean it was nighttime, and even though Harry was in trouble, the door wasn’t locked for the night.

> “Uncle Vernon waited until Piers was safely out of the house before starting on Harry. He was so angry he could hardly speak. He managed to say, ‘Go – cupboard – stay – no meals,’ before he collapsed into a chair and Aunt Petunia had to run and get him a large brandy.
>
> *
>
> Harry lay in his dark cupboard much later, wishing he had a watch. He didn’t know what time it was and he couldn’t be sure the Dursleys were asleep yet. Until they were, he couldn’t risk sneaking to the kitchen for some food.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 2 (The Vanishing Glass)*</sup></sub>

They did, however, lock him in the cupboard sometimes, usually it seems as punishment. When he ended on top of his school, he’d been locked in there, though it’s not said how long.

> “The Dursleys had received a very angry letter from Harry’s headmistress telling them Harry had been climbing school buildings. But all he’d tried to do (as he shouted at Uncle Vernon through the locked door of his cupboard) was jump behind the big bins outside the kitchen doors. Harry supposed that the wind must have caught him in mid-jump.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 2 (The Vanishing Glass)*</sup></sub>

In addition, Harry wonders how he could possibly be a wizard if the Dursleys could lock him in the cupboard.

> “He’d spent his life being clouted by Dudley and bullied by Aunt Petunia and Uncle Vernon; if he was really a wizard, why hadn’t they been turned into warty toads every time they’d tried to lock him in his cupboard?” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 4 (The Keeper of the Keys)*</sup></sub>

From that, it’s clear that they have locked him up multiple times, since it’s the first punishment he thinks of.

## When they did lock him up all day, he got two bathroom breaks.

Once Vernon Dursley saw the warning Harry got and realized that Harry wasn’t allowed to do magic outside of school even though he was acting like he could, he got furious and locked Harry in his bedroom all day. Harry was allowed out to use the bathroom twice, once in the morning, once in the evening.

> “He was bearing down on Harry like a great bulldog, all his teeth bared. ‘Well, I’ve got news for you, boy … I’m locking you up … you’re never going back to that school … never … and if you try and magic yourself out – they’ll expel you!’
>   And laughing like a maniac, he dragged Harry back upstairs.
>
> Uncle Vernon was as bad as his word. The following morning, he paid a man to fit bars on Harry’s window. He himself fitted the cat-flap in the bedroom door, so that small amounts of food could be pushed inside three times a day. They let Harry out to use the bathroom morning and evening. Otherwise, he was locked in his room around the clock.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, Chapter 2 (Dobby’s Warning)*</sup></sub>

He was allowed two bathroom breaks, but it’s not clear if the Dursleys would have let him out for another one if he needed it. (They were very upset with him, but they also wouldn’t want pee anywhere it shouldn’t be in their nice clean house.) Harry also wasn’t being fed much at that point, he’d get a bit of food but not much (which he had to share between himself and Hedwig), so that would make him less likely to need additional trips to the bathroom.